# ResponseWriter interface in Go net/http package

Tags: http, go

I have two questions about the ResponseWriter interface in net/http package. Here is my code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type handler struct{}

func (h *handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Method: %v\n", req.Method)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "URL: %v\n", req.URL)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Protocol: %v\n", req.Proto)

    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Header: %v\n", w.Header())
}

func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", &handler{})
}
```

and to check the code I used curl in cmd. Below you can see the curl command and its result.

```
C:\Users>curl -i -X GET localhost:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 19 Aug 2022 03:47:21 GMT
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Method: GET
URL: /
Protocol: HTTP/1.1
```

Since http.ResponseWriter is only an interface and I have not implemented any concrete type in my program to satisfy this interface, why is my code working? As far as I understood there is no implementation for interface methods. So how do I get a correct response from curl?

Also, as you can see in the output of curl, I am receiving an http response with a header. However, output of `fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Header: %v\n", w.Header())` is `Header: map[]`. If I am right, Header method for http.ResponseWriter must return the response header which is not empty based on the curl output. So why does `Fprintf` return an empty map?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's implemented by an unexported type, the default header stuff is set by this unexported type. (unexported in Go is similar to "private" in other languages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since http.ResponseWriter is only an interface and I have not implemented any concrete type in my program to satisfy this interface, why is my code working?

*You* haven't; the standard library has (namely, the private `http.response` and `http.http2responsewriter` types). The http server passes an instance of one of those types in to your handler. You don't need to know what it is; you just know that whatever you get, it will implement the `ResponseWriter` methods.

> So why does Fprintf return an empty map?

Because the map is empty, because you didn't set any headers. Some servers (like `Date` and `Content-Type`) can be set automatically by the server if you don't set them yourself, but this is happening *after* the point where you are printing.